# Timing in sending a PHP form by email

Tags: php, email

I have a form to be send by email. Everything is working but since I press the bottom to be sent until the screen changes to "Thank you for contacting us" it takes 1 minute and 2 seconds. I'm working in Ubuntu with Apache.

Why is that slow? Anything I can do to speed it up?

Thanks

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="sendrequest.php">
Select Number of Guests
<select name="numberofguests">
 <option value="1">1</option> 
 <option value="2">2</option> 
 <option value="3">3</option> 
</select> 
<br>

Select a date:
<br>
<input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Request">
</form>
```

Then I have my sendrequest.php file to send the info by email as follow:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Subject";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['numberofguests']) ||
    !isset($_POST['date'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$numberofguests = $_POST['numberofguests']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['date']; // required
 }
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Number of Guests: ".clean_string($numberofguests)."\n";
$email_message .= "Date: ".clean_string($date)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");
?>

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
//die();
?>
```

Comment: are you using smtp sendmail?

Comment: Are you receiving the mail you send? I have run into something similar before. Agree with @thewbstr that it may be in how your mail is being delivered in Ubuntu. I prefer Postfix. Easy, consistent, fast... but it doesn't come pre-installed or pre-configured.

Comment: Yes I'm using sendmail, which it wasn't preconfig either. I had to donlowaded. And yes, I'm sending the email to myself as testing. But it is not that the email take 1 minute to get to my inbox, but the .php site takes a minute to refresh and said that email was send. From a user prospective, the user might think that it is not working because it is taking so long to respond.